# Node, Yarn, Javascript - Error installing setprotocol dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

I am getting following error when adding a "setprotocol.js" dependency using Yarn (`yarn add setprotocol.js`) to my project. I am not familiar with Node or Yarn. I ran into this error when following [this](https://docs.setprotocol.com/#/getting-started#summary) Set Protocol tutorial.

I am on a mac.
My yarn version is 1.22.5
My node version is v12.18.2
My xcode version is 12.0.1

Error:

```
make: *** [Release/obj.target/scrypt/src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_params_async.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/septerr/src/personal/setprotocol/node_modules/scrypt
```

Full console log:

```
septerr@septerr setprotocol %  yarn add setprotocol.js                                                          
yarn add v1.22.5
warning package.json: No license field
warning No license field
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
warning setprotocol.js > truffle-hdwallet-provider@1.0.17: WARNING: This package has been renamed to @truffle/hdwallet-provider.
warning setprotocol.js > set-protocol-viewers > zos-lib@2.4.3: This package has been renamed to @openzeppelin/upgrades. Please update your dependency, or you will no longer receive updates.
warning setprotocol.js > set-protocol-contracts > zos-lib@2.4.3: This package has been renamed to @openzeppelin/upgrades. Please update your dependency, or you will no longer receive updates.
warning setprotocol.js > set-protocol-strategies > set-protocol-contracts > zos-lib@2.4.3: This package has been renamed to @openzeppelin/upgrades. Please update your dependency, or you will no longer receive updates.
warning setprotocol.js > set-protocol-viewers > set-protocol-contracts > zos-lib@2.4.3: This package has been renamed to @openzeppelin/upgrades. Please update your dependency, or you will no longer receive updates.
warning setprotocol.js > set-protocol-viewers > zos-lib > @types/web3@1.2.2: This is a stub types definition. web3 provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
warning setprotocol.js > set-protocol-strategies > set-protocol-contract-utils > zos-lib@2.4.3: This package has been renamed to @openzeppelin/upgrades. Please update your dependency, or you will no longer receive updates.
warning setprotocol.js > set-protocol-oracles > eth-gas-reporter > request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning setprotocol.js > set-protocol-oracles > eth-gas-reporter > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning setprotocol.js > set-protocol-oracles > ethlint > chokidar@1.7.0: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
warning setprotocol.js > set-protocol-oracles > eth-gas-reporter > mocha > mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
warning setprotocol.js > set-protocol-oracles > minify-all > node-minify > mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
warning setprotocol.js > set-protocol-viewers > zos-lib > lodash.isarray@4.0.0: This package is deprecated. Use Array.isArray.
warning setprotocol.js > tiny-promisify > babel-runtime > core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
warning setprotocol.js > web3-utils > eth-lib > servify > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning setprotocol.js > set-protocol-oracles > chainlink > chainlinkv0.5 > truffle-contract@4.0.31: WARNING: This package has been renamed to @truffle/contract.
warning setprotocol.js > set-protocol-oracles > eth-gas-reporter > request > har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
warning setprotocol.js > set-protocol-oracles > ethlint > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
warning setprotocol.js > set-protocol-oracles > minify-all > node-minify > node-uuid@1.4.7: Use uuid module instead
warning setprotocol.js > truffle > mocha > yargs-unparser > flat@4.1.0: Fixed a prototype pollution security issue in 4.1.0, please upgrade to ^4.1.1 or ^5.0.1.
warning setprotocol.js > web3 > web3-bzz > swarm-js > mkdirp-promise@5.0.1: This package is broken and no longer maintained. 'mkdirp' itself supports promises now, please switch to that.
warning setprotocol.js > truffle-hdwallet-provider > web3 > web3-bzz > swarm-js > mkdirp-promise@5.0.1: This package is broken and no longer maintained. 'mkdirp' itself supports promises now, please switch to that.
warning setprotocol.js > set-protocol-viewers > zos-lib > @types/web3 > web3 > web3-bzz > swarm-js > mkdirp-promise@5.0.1: This package is broken and no longer maintained. 'mkdirp' itself supports promises now, please switch to that.
warning setprotocol.js > web3 > web3-bzz > swarm-js > fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
warning setprotocol.js > web3 > web3-bzz > swarm-js > tar.gz@1.0.7: ⚠️  WARNING ⚠️ tar.gz module has been deprecated and your application is vulnerable. Please use tar module instead: https://npmjs.com/tar
warning setprotocol.js > set-protocol-oracles > chainlink > chainlinkv0.5 > truffle-contract > truffle-interface-adapter@0.2.5: WARNING: This package has been renamed to @truffle/interface-adapter.
warning setprotocol.js > set-protocol-oracles > truffle-flattener > @resolver-engine/imports-fs > @resolver-engine/imports > @resolver-engine/core > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning setprotocol.js > set-protocol-viewers > zos-lib > @types/web3 > web3 > web3-eth > web3-eth-ens > content-hash > multicodec@0.5.7: stable api reached
warning setprotocol.js > set-protocol-oracles > lint-staged > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
warning setprotocol.js > set-protocol-oracles > lint-staged > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning "setprotocol.js > chai-as-promised@7.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "chai@>= 2.1.2 < 5".
warning "setprotocol.js > set-protocol-oracles > ts-mocha@6.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "mocha@^3.X.X || ^4.X.X || ^5.X.X || ^6.X.X".
warning "setprotocol.js > set-protocol-oracles > ts-node@8.10.2" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.7".
warning "setprotocol.js > set-protocol-oracles > tslint-eslint-rules@5.4.0" has unmet peer dependency "tslint@^5.0.0".
warning "setprotocol.js > set-protocol-oracles > tslint-eslint-rules@5.4.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@^2.2.0 || ^3.0.0".
warning "setprotocol.js > set-protocol-oracles > bn-chai@1.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "chai@>= 2.1.2 < 5".
warning "setprotocol.js > set-protocol-oracles > ethlint > solium-plugin-security@0.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "solium@^1.0.0".
warning "setprotocol.js > set-protocol-oracles > tslint-eslint-rules > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
[8/25] ⠄ scrypt
[-/25] ⠄ waiting...
[-/25] ⠄ waiting...
[-/25] ⠄ waiting...
error /Users/septerr/src/personal/setprotocol/node_modules/scrypt: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-gyp rebuild
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/septerr/src/personal/setprotocol/node_modules/scrypt
Output:
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.1.0
gyp info using node@12.18.2 | darwin | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.16 found at "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python"
gyp info spawn /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/septerr/src/personal/setprotocol/node_modules/scrypt/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/septerr/src/personal/setprotocol/node_modules/scrypt',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/copied_files.node
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/scrypt_wrapper/src/util/memlimit.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/scrypt_wrapper/src/scryptwrapper/keyderivation.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/scrypt_wrapper/src/scryptwrapper/pickparams.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/scrypt_wrapper/src/scryptwrapper/hash.o
  LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/scrypt_wrapper.a
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/scrypt_lib/scrypt/scrypt-1.2.0/lib/crypto/crypto_scrypt.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/scrypt_lib/scrypt/scrypt-1.2.0/lib/crypto/crypto_scrypt_smix.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/scrypt_lib/scrypt/scrypt-1.2.0/libcperciva/util/warnp.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/scrypt_lib/scrypt/scrypt-1.2.0/libcperciva/alg/sha256.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/scrypt_lib/scrypt/scrypt-1.2.0/libcperciva/util/insecure_memzero.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/scrypt_lib/scrypt/scrypt-1.2.0/lib/scryptenc/scryptenc_cpuperf.o
  LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/scrypt_lib.a
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/scrypt/src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_common.o
../src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_common.cc:98:12: warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'scrypt_err_description' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
    return scrypt_err_description.c_str();
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/scrypt/src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_params_async.o
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_params_async.cc:4:
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_params_async.h:28:
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_async.h:28:
../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_common.h:39:14: warning: 'Get' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      N(obj->Get(Nan::New("N").ToLocalChecked())->Uint32Value()),
             ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8.h:3553:3: note: 'Get' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATED("Use maybe version", Local<Value> Get(Local<Value> key));
  ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8config.h:328:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATED'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_params_async.cc:4:
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_params_async.h:28:
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_async.h:28:
../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_common.h:39:63: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'context' was not specified
      N(obj->Get(Nan::New("N").ToLocalChecked())->Uint32Value()),
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8.h:2707:3: note: 'Uint32Value' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<uint32_t> Uint32Value(
  ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8config.h:368:31: note: expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
                              ^
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_params_async.cc:4:
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_params_async.h:28:
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_async.h:28:
../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_common.h:40:14: warning: 'Get' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      r(obj->Get(Nan::New("r").ToLocalChecked())->Uint32Value()),
             ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8.h:3553:3: note: 'Get' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATED("Use maybe version", Local<Value> Get(Local<Value> key));
  ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8config.h:328:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATED'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_params_async.cc:4:
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_params_async.h:28:
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_async.h:28:
../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_common.h:40:63: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'context' was not specified
      r(obj->Get(Nan::New("r").ToLocalChecked())->Uint32Value()),
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8.h:2707:3: note: 'Uint32Value' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<uint32_t> Uint32Value(
  ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8config.h:368:31: note: expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
                              ^
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_params_async.cc:4:
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_params_async.h:28:
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_async.h:28:
../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_common.h:41:14: warning: 'Get' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      p(obj->Get(Nan::New("p").ToLocalChecked())->Uint32Value()) {}
             ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8.h:3553:3: note: 'Get' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATED("Use maybe version", Local<Value> Get(Local<Value> key));
  ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8config.h:328:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATED'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_params_async.cc:4:
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_params_async.h:28:
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_async.h:28:
../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_common.h:41:63: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'context' was not specified
      p(obj->Get(Nan::New("p").ToLocalChecked())->Uint32Value()) {}
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8.h:2707:3: note: 'Uint32Value' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<uint32_t> Uint32Value(
  ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8config.h:368:31: note: expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
                              ^
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_params_async.cc:4:
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_params_async.h:28:
../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_async.h:53:17: warning: 'Call' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      callback->Call(1, argv);
                ^
../../nan/nan.h:1741:3: note: 'Call' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value>
  ^
../../nan/nan.h:106:40: note: expanded from macro 'NAN_DEPRECATED'
# define NAN_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
                                       ^
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_params_async.cc:4:
../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_params_async.h:35:36: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'context' was not specified
      maxtime(info[0]->NumberValue()),
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8.h:2704:3: note: 'NumberValue' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<double> NumberValue(Local<Context> context) const;
  ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8config.h:368:31: note: expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
                              ^
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_params_async.cc:4:
../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_params_async.h:36:39: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'context' was not specified
      maxmemfrac(info[1]->NumberValue()),
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8.h:2704:3: note: 'NumberValue' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<double> NumberValue(Local<Context> context) const;
  ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8config.h:368:31: note: expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
                              ^
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_params_async.cc:4:
../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_params_async.h:37:36: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'context' was not specified
      maxmem(info[2]->IntegerValue()),
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8.h:2705:3: note: 'IntegerValue' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<int64_t> IntegerValue(
  ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8config.h:368:31: note: expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
                              ^
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_params_async.cc:4:
../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_params_async.h:38:39: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'context' was not specified
      osfreemem(info[3]->IntegerValue())
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8.h:2705:3: note: 'IntegerValue' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<int64_t> IntegerValue(
  ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8config.h:368:31: note: expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
                              ^
../src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_params_async.cc:23:8: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  obj->Set(Nan::New("N").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<Integer>(logN));
       ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8.h:3498:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATED("Use maybe version",
  ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8config.h:328:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATED'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
../src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_params_async.cc:24:8: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  obj->Set(Nan::New("r").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<Integer>(r));
       ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8.h:3498:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATED("Use maybe version",
  ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8config.h:328:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATED'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
../src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_params_async.cc:25:8: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  obj->Set(Nan::New("p").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<Integer>(p));
       ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8.h:3498:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATED("Use maybe version",
  ^
/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/v8config.h:328:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATED'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
../src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_params_async.cc:32:13: warning: 'Call' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  callback->Call(2, argv);
            ^
../../nan/nan.h:1741:3: note: 'Call' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value>
  ^
../../nan/nan.h:106:40: note: expanded from macro 'NAN_DEPRECATED'
# define NAN_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
                                       ^
8 warnings and 7 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/scrypt/src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_params_async.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/septerr/src/personal/setprotocol/node_modules/scrypt
```

Running `node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild` results in:

```
septerr@septerr setprotocol % node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.1.0
gyp info using node@12.18.2 | darwin | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.16 found at "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python"
gyp info spawn /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/septerr/src/personal/setprotocol/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/septerr/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/septerr/src/personal/setprotocol',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: /Users/septerr/src/personal/setprotocol) while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/septerr/src/personal/setprotocol
gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: Did you try `rm` your node_modules directory and rm your yarn.lock and package-lock.json (NOT package.json) and rerunning yarn?